# ¿Como calcular el tiempo de una publicación?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy realizando un proyecto tipo blog y estoy tratando de hacer una función que cuando el usuario publique, su post tenga todo la info que publico y también mostrarle hace cuanto publico, como lo tienen todas las redes sociales.

[image: tiempo de publicación]

Dejo un ejemplo.

```
export function fecha() {
    const fechaNueva = new Date();

    const opcionesConfig = {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: '2-digit',
    }

    return fechaNueva.toLocaleDateString('en-US', opcionesConfig);
}
```

Me da la siguiente salida de consola = November 22, 2022
Yo necesito que diga = hace 1min cuando el usuario publique.

Comment: Quedé esperando el ejemplo. Qué has intentado? Qué hay de malo tener un timestamp cuando guardas el post y luego lo muestras en el front end? Cuál es tu problema específico?

Comment: Ahí edite el post, con lo que intente

Comment: Tienes que restar la fecha actual del sistema con la fecha en la que se creó ese post... y basado en eso calculas el tiempo transcurrido

Comment: Gracias pipe, ya lo pude realizar